# Android Studio keeps sending sms

Tags: java, android, sms

I have a problem with sending SMS.

it keeps sending SMS. How to only send one SMS?

the text toast will keep on displaying, you have to close the app to stop sending sms.

I try the return, but it is not work.

```
  private void sendSMS(String address, String time){
  
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("pre_key_name", null);
        String phoneNum = sharedPreferences.getString("pre_key_phone", null);
        String smsContent = time + name + "in" + address + "falls！";
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, smsContent ,null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "message send success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

```
public Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if(msg.arg1 > 0){
                countingView.setText("                         " + msg.arg1 + context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.fall_contacts));
            }else{
                if(dialog != null){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if(isVibrate){
                        stopVibrate();
                    }
                    stopAlarm();
                    sendSMS(locationAddress, locationTime);
                    return;
                }
                timer.cancel();

            }


        }

    };
```

Comment: Assuming that's a `Timer` `Handler`, shouldn't the `return` be deleted so the `timer.cancel()` can cancel it? Otherwise, we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an SMS has been sent or not, just use a boolean value.

```
private boolean hasSentSMS = false; //declaring outside of the handler
 if (!hasSentSMS) {
    sendSMS(locationAddress, locationTime);
    hasSentSMS = true;
}
```